# Class UserIdentity not returning properties in Yii

Tags: php, yii

i made this code with a tutorial:

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;
    private $_email;

    public function authenticate()
    {
        $user=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
        if($user===null)
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        else if($user->password!==md5($this->password))
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        else
        {
            $this->_id=$user->id;
            $this->_email=$user->email;
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

And i try to save that ID of the user, but it does not return the ID, it returns the emailadres, and the email is not defined when calling it like:

```
echo Yii::app()->user->email;
```

Please help me! Im new to Yii!

Comment: so when using `Yii::app()->user->id` you are getting the email address? Is this correct? and when calling `Yii::app()->user->email` you are getting undefined or a blank result?

Comment: @TheHumbleRat yes that's true. Weird isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override two methods of `CUserIdentity`:

1. getName() //to get user name
2. getId() //to get user id

So you would have two properties by default:

```
private $_name;
private $_id;
```

And you need to override mentioned methods:

```
public function getId() {
    return $this->_id;
}

public function getName() {
    return $this->_name;
}
```

And

```
$this->_id=$user->id;
$this->name=$user->username;
```

If you want to to save another user info such as email, you can use `setState()`, for example:

```
$this->_id=$user->id;
$this->name=$user->username;
$this->setState('email', $user->email);
```

Then use it in your project like below:

```
Yii::app()->user->getState('email'); //will return stored email in session
```

To get `id` , `name` you can use:

```
$id=Yii::app()->user->id;
$name=Yii::app()->user->name;
```

In your case, it seems, yii is overriding `name` with email.

Comment: Thanks mate, that worked! One more question, is this save enough to save the records from users in there? except for password, that's never smart.

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl When you load a model, save will take place if you call it.

Comment: yes i know, it works already but is it safe to save the data like that?

Comment: Yes, it is. For exmaple you may need to update last login date of user. The right place is here. You might want to read about filters in yii which you can do similar things more elegant.

Comment: Got a link for me to something about filters? Like a tutorial or something?